# handle loading and no content separately

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, immutable.js

In my application, I get the content from the API. I could show the content and also show the loader icon until the content is not loaded. But if there is no any content, the page shows loader icon which is unexpected. The expected functionality is to show no content available if there is no content at all.

```
render() {
    const { logs } = this.state;
    if (logs.size === undefined) {
      return <div>No Logs</div>;
    } else if (isEmpty(logs)) {
      return (
        <div className="earth-spinning">
          <img src={EarthSpinning} alt="spinner" style={{ margin: "0 auto" }} />
        </div>
      );
    } else {
      return (
        <div>
          <h2>Logs</h2>
          <button onClick={() => this.props.deleteLogs()}>
            Delete All Logs
          </button>
          <ul className="list-group">
            {this.renderLogs()}
            {this.state.show ? this.props.dialog : null}
          </ul>
        </div>
      );
    }
  }
```

This is the data i get

[image]

Comment: What is `isEmpty` and could you give us a sample of the content from the API?

Comment: Updated my question. isEmpty is checking whether the object is empty or not.

Comment: @AndrewLi for more detail, you can go to the following link https://gist.github.com/anonymous/e1dd5e91297108dadcc6e61d3c08a394

Comment: Note that it is considered an anti pattern to store props in state like your doing. It would be better to convert your logs to plain JS before being passed to the component as props, or doing it at the time it is needed as plain JS

Comment: Can you comment out in the gist i have provided you, please?

Answer (score 0):

Its good to have APIs return promises so that you can respond to when they are complete

this example assume you would do you API call and the data would go to a store and that would come in on props

```
...

getInitialState() {
    return {
        loading: true
    };
}

componentWillMount() {
   this.props.requestLogs()
       .then(() => this.setState({ loading: false });
}

render() {
    if (this.state.loading) {
        return this.renderLoading();
    }

    if (this.props.logs.length === 0) {
        return this.renderEmptyView();
    }

    return this.renderStuff();
}
```

Comment: I get `TypeError: this.props.requestLogs(...).then is not a function` error

Comment: tried in both componendDidMount and WillMount but nowhere its working

Comment: this.props.requestLogs would need to be a function that returns a promise.

Comment: I'm not sure what your api call in `logRequest` but perhaps take a look at the [fetch api](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) as well as [promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)

Comment: I have udpated my gist https://gist.github.com/SanskarSans/07454fb8c77ad608189b4ac567813c1c

Comment: It still doesn't show what the implementation of your `./actions` file is. It looks like you're using generator functions, which don't return promises, but instead return an iterator. either way its good practice for all your actions to return promises